# Eager loading and detaching EF context

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, caching, enterprise-library

I want to retrieve entities using EF.

I then save them in enterprise_library_cache

I get **sometimes** an error "ObjectContext was disposed already"

I'm uging `using` at a very high leve - one per request, but I guess the entities are used after thier contextObject were disposed.

I think this will solve my problem:

How do I force eager loading from DB (including all forigen keys, meaning nested entities) +

detaching it from any context ?

Comment: Look, for example, at Include extension method :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679205%28v=vs.103%29.aspx . If your not in EF 5.0, the overload with an `Expression<Func<T, TProperty>>` parameter also exists in System.Data.Entity, while overload with string parameter is (if I'm not wrong) in System.Linq.

Comment: I have entities with references to entities. Including any one of them is not that elegant

Comment: what happens when I attach entity which is already attached?